# Looking for a tool to monitor process exceptions with stack traces in real-time

Tags: powershell, exception, stack-trace, developer-tools, procdump

I want to be able to monitor process exceptions with stack traces in real-time, while they occurred. I'd like to do that on a client PC, while I don't have any developing tools installed, nor do I wish to install large tools on it.

I tried procdump with the following command:

```
procdump -e 1 -l -f "" <procname>
```

This allows me to monitor process only exceptions in real-time as they occur. However, I’m looking for a solution that not only shows the exceptions but also provides a stack trace for each exception.

Is there a free tool available that offers this functionality? Alternatively, could a PowerShell script be written to achieve this? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I don't want to create a dump file for a later inspection. I rather like to see the exceptions with their traces as they occurred.

Comment: Assuming symbols are available on the client, WinDBG (or it's command-line sibling `cdb`) can parse the dump and output the call stack at the exception site - but that'll require installation

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I'm searching for a real-time solution rather than a later inspection of a dump-file. I have edited my question to emphasize it. Thanks

Comment: What are you expecting the experience to be? Would a new window appear for each exception?

Comment: @lit, the procdump tool which I mentioned, shows the exceptions on the console it runs on, whenever they occurred, one after one. As long as it gives me a way to look at the list of occurred exceptions + stack traces, that's fine with me.